# Vaal grid height is too big

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Vaadin (7.6.6) grid to show some java beans, which is in a layout

```
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.setSpacing(true);
layout.setMargin(true);
List<Booster> boosters = new ArrayList<>();
boosters.add(creaBoost("e"));
boosters.add(creaBoost("f"));
boosters.add(creaBoost("g"));
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<>(Booster.class, boosters));
grid.setWidth("80%");
grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
grid.removeColumn("ident");
layout.addComponent(grid);

Button button = new Button("Delete", FontAwesome.WARNING);
button.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_DANGER);
layout.addComponent(button);
```

which results in the following
[image]
I was wondering, where this height came from ? Is there a way to reduce it and only show the actual height it requires ?

Ideally it takes into account to not get higher than X, so that if more elements are part of the grid, it does not grow constantly ?

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to functions (setHeightMode, setHeightByRows) to define the height by interpreting the quantity of the grid-elements or set it to a specific amount of visible rows.

```
    Grid myGrid = new Grid();
    VerticalLayout test = new VerticalLayout();

    Bill testBill = new Bill(23, "Test", "Products", 3, new Date(), new Date());
    BeanItemContainer<Bill> testItemContainer = new BeanItemContainer<Bill>(Bill.class);

    testItemContainer.addItem(testBill);

    myGrid.setContainerDataSource(testItemContainer);
    test.addComponent(myGrid);

    myGrid.setHeightMode(HeightMode.ROW);
    myGrid.setHeightByRows(testItemContainer.size());
```

Comment: this works great when the number of elements is less than it can display (for me about 10 elements). when `testItemContainer.size()` is greater than that, I only see the first 10 elements and no scrollbar. When sorting a column, the grid jumps to its full size and shows all elements.

Comment: Mh... that's odd. 

When I have 30 elements in my BeanItemContainer and limit the grid to 10, there are **only 10 visible**, **scrolling** is working and sorting a column doesn't make any problems either. 

I am using a fresh Vaadin archetype... Maybe you have some styling, which affects the grid?

Comment: Here is my example... [Screenshot](http://lb-photography.de/uploads/gridSize.jpg)

Comment: thanks for the code - using this gives me the expected behaviour - but unfortunately it comes with side effects for following components in the layout. see http://imgur.com/a/ZdT6T . the first image is without the `setHeightxxx` methods. The following panel is shown correctly. The second image uses the methods, and the panel is cut... when I sort the grid, then the page is reloaded or so, but the panel is shown correctly

Comment: i have tried to set explicit heights on the layout and on the panel, but this changed nothing

Comment: Sorry, I can't really reconstruct your sideaffects. I put the grid and a _FormGroup_ in two different _Panels_. Setting the grid height by row-quantity works like a charm. Don't know why this affecting your login-form-panel...